# Magento2 - accessing helper in controller

Tags: controllers, helper, custom-block

I have helper class that has constructor that takes following parameters: Context, Cart, Session, CollectionFactory. It derives from `\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper`.

I would like to use this helper inside of my frontend controller but I don't know what to do to make my controller constructor called with extra parameters so that I could use them to initialize my helper class.

Point is - I would like to have access to Context, Cart, Session, CollectionFactory in controller that derives from `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`.

Here is source code of my controller and part of the helper class:

```
<?php
namespace Something\Something\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        echo $some_json_that_i_will_use_in_the_frontend;
    }
}
```

Helper:

```
<?php

namespace Something\Something\Helper;

use \Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    private $cart;

    private $customerSession;

    private $orderCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context, Cart $cart, Session $customerSession, CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add your controller and helper file to your question?

Comment: I have edited my post and attached source code of controller and helper

Comment: Why not you have injected the cart, session etc to your controller instead of helper? If you also need those in helper then you need to inject those both in controller and in helper. This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code for controller file:

```
<?php
namespace Something\Something\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_cart;
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart, 
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, 
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ){
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {

        echo $some_json_that_i_will_use_in_the_frontend;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats great, what about using scope config?:
`$this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::something, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE`

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting this exception `Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function _construct`

Comment: When are you getting this error? During di compile?

Comment: I was trying to call constructor without compiling di, thank you so much!

Comment: So its working now?

Comment: So far so good!

Answer (score 0):

```
       <?php
    namespace Something\Something\Controller\Index;

  class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
  {
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $helper;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Something\Something\Helper $helper
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
      $this->helper = $helper;
      $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
      return parent::__construct($context);
    }

  public function execute()
  {

    echo $some_json_that_i_will_use_in_the_frontend;
  }
}
```